Deriving equation (3-66) of Papoulis and Pillai
$$
\mbox{The identity is}\quad
P_{2n+2} = P_{2n} + {2n \choose n}p^{n+2}q^n - {2n \choose n+1}p^{n+1}q^{n+1}
$$
$\displaystyle\mbox{where}\
P_{2n} = \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}{2n \choose k}p^kq^{2n-k}
\quad$ and $\displaystyle\quad P_{2n+2} = \sum_{k=n+2}^{2n+2}{2n+2 \choose k}p^kq^{2n+2-k}$.

$p$ and $q$ are in the range $\left[0, 1\right]$ and
$p = 1 - q$.
I am confused how it is possible since $P_{2n+2}$ involves ${2n+2 \choose k}$.
Then I wrote a program and tested this identity.
Could you please help me to derive this identity ?.
It is bugging me a lot. This identity appears on the page $69$ of the book Probability,Random Variables and Stochastic Processes by Papoulis and Pillai, $4$th edition.

Thanks.

I'm sure there are many books titled "Probability, Random Variables, and Stochastic Processes." Can you include the author, in case any of us has that text?

Of course. The book was written by Athanasios Papoulis, 4th edition

Is $n$ any natural number here? At first glance for a problem like this, I would try combining like terms from P_{2n} and P_{2n+2} on common terms (based on, say, the exponent of p) and there's often a way to get a common denominator by expanding out the binomial coefficient for algebraic simplification.

Yes n is natural number >= 1 @locallytrivial

If we drop the condition $p+q=1$, what seems to be going on is that $$P_{2n+2} - {2n \choose n}p^{n+2}q^n + {2n \choose n+1}p^{n+1}q^{n+1}=(p+q)^2 P_{2n}$$ This of course simplifies to the given identity when $p+q=1$.

I derived it. Thank you everyone.

We have that
$$P_{2n} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {2n\choose k} p^{2n-k} q^k
= p^{2n} [z^{n-1}] \frac{1}{1-z} (1+qz/p)^{2n}
\\ = p^2 [z^{n-1}] \frac{1}{1-p^2z} (1+pqz)^{2n}
= p^2 [z^{n+1}] z^2 \frac{1}{1-p^2z} (1+pqz)^{2n}.$$
We also have
$${2n\choose n} p^{n+2} q^n = p^2 [z^n] (1+pqz)^{2n}
= p^2 [z^{n+1}] z (1+pqz)^{2n}$$
and
$${2n\choose n+1} p^{n+1} q^{n+1} =
p^2 q^2 [z^{n-1}] (1+pqz)^{2n}
= p^2 q^2 [z^{n+1}] z^2 (1+pqz)^{2n}.$$
Observe that
$$P_{2n+2} = \sum_{k=0}^n {2n+2\choose k} p^{2n+2-k} q^k
= p^2 [z^n] \frac{1}{1-p^2z} (1+pqz)^{2n+2}
\\ = p^2 [z^{n+1}] z (1+pqz)^2 \frac{1}{1-p^2z} (1+pqz)^{2n}.$$
To conclude collect the first three contributions to get
$$p^2 z^2 \frac{1}{1-p^2z} + p^2 z - p^2 q^2 z^2
= p^2 z \left[ \frac{z}{1-p^2z} + 1 - q^2 z \right]
\\ = \frac{p^2 z}{1-p^2 z}
\left[ z + (1-q^2z) (1-p^2z) \right]
= \frac{p^2 z}{1-p^2 z}
\left[ z + 1 - (p^2+q^2) z + p^2 q^2 z^2 \right].$$
Note however that $1 - p^2 - q^2 = 1 - p (1-q) - q (1-p) = 2pq$ so we get
$$\frac{p^2 z}{1-p^2 z} ( 1 + pqz )^2$$
and we have the claim.

$\displaystyle +1$. Pretty fine.

Here is my development of the argument given in Papoulis and Pillai.
First,we may use the binomial expansion to write
$$(p+q)^{2n}=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k}p^k q^{2n-k}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{k}p^k q^{2n-k}+\underbrace{\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k}p^k q^{2n-k}}_{P_{2n}}$$
An analogous expression applies for $(p+q)^{2n+2}$. Hence we may write
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{2n+2}{k}p^k q^{2n+2-k}+P_{2n+2}=(p+q)^2\left[\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{k} p^k q^{2n-k}+P_{2n}\right]
$$
Grouping the $P_{2n},P_{2n+2}$ terms on one side, we obtain
\begin{align}
P_{2n+2}-(p+q)^2 P_{2n} &=(p+q)^2\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{k} p^k q^{2n-k}-\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{2n+2}{k}p^k q^{2n+2-k}\tag{1}
\end{align}
To proceed further, I'll distribute the first product and organize to have common terms $p^k q^{2n+2-k}$. I will also initiate the following convention: Since $\binom{2n}{k}=0$ unless $k\geq 0$, I will assume each summation to begin at $k=-\infty$ and suppress this notationally. Hence
\begin{align}
&(p+q)^2\sum_{k}^{n}\binom{2n}{k} p^k q^{2n-k}\\
&\quad=(p^2+2pq+q^2)\sum_{k}^{n}\binom{2n}{k} p^k q^{2n-k}\\
&\quad=\sum_{k}^{n}\binom{2n}{k} p^{k+2} q^{2n-k}+\sum_{k}^{n}2\binom{2n}{k} p^{k+1} q^{2n+1-k}+\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{k} p^{k} q^{2n+2-k}\\
&\quad=\sum_{k}^{n+2}\binom{2n}{k-2} p^{k} q^{2n+2-k}+\sum_{k}^{n+1}2\binom{2n}{k-1} p^{k} q^{2n+2-k}+\sum_{k}^{n}\binom{2n}{k} p^{k} q^{2n+2-k}\\
&\quad=\sum_{k}^{n+1}\left[\binom{2n}{k-2}+2\binom{2n}{k-1}+\binom{2n}{k}\right] p^{k} q^{2n+2-k}+\binom{2n}{n} p^{n+2} q^{n}-\binom{2n}{n+1} p^{n+1} q^{n+1}
\end{align}
The terms in square brackets are then an instance of Vandermonde's identity, namely
$$\sum_{m=0}^2 \binom{2}{m}\binom{2n}{k-m}=\binom{2n+2}{k}$$
Hence everything on the RHS of (1) cancels except for the two leftover terms:
$$P_{2n+2}-(p+q)^2 P_{2n}=\binom{2n}{n} p^{n+2} q^{n}-\binom{2n}{n+1} p^{n+1} q^{n+1}$$
Applying $p+q=1$ on the LHS then yields the desired result.

We have the sequence
$$
P_{2n} = \sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{2n} \binom{2n}{k} p^k q^{2n-k}.
$$
It contains the terms of $(p+q)^{2n}$ for powers of $q$ from $0$ to $n-1$. One concise way to formulate it is
$$
P_{2n}\equiv (p+q)^{2n} \pmod{q^n}.
$$
In the expression above, we treat $p$ as a constant, and $q$ as a formal variable. Defined this way, powers of $q$ larger or equal than $n$ will get nullified. Now, we can express $P_{2n+2}$ as
$$
P_{2n+2} \equiv (p+q)^{2n+2} \equiv (p+q)^2 (p+q)^{2n}\pmod{q^{n+1}}.
$$
Then, we can express $(p+q)^{2n}$ modulo $q^{n+1}$ if we know $(p+q)^{2n}$ modulo $q^n$, which is $P_{2n}$:
$$
(p+q)^{2n} \equiv P_{2n} + \binom{2n}{n} p^n q^n \pmod{q^{n+1}}.
$$
Plugging it back, we have
$$
P_{2n+2} \equiv (p+q)^2 P_{2n} + (p+q)^2\binom{2n}{n} p^nq^n \pmod{q^{n+1}}
$$
When we take the right hand side modulo $q^{n+1}$, we need to get rid of the terms having power of $q$ larger than $n$ to get an exact formula for $P_{2n+2}$. For the second summand it means changing it into $\binom{2n}{n} p^{n+2} q^n$, as summands with powers of $q$ larger than $n$ get nullified. Correspondingly, when we take the first summand modulo $q^{n+1}$, we get something that is almost $(p+q)^2 P_{2n}$ itself, except that we need to cancel the only summand that is a multiple of $q^{n+1}$, which is $\binom{2n}{n+1}p^{n+1}q^{n+1}$. This yields the final formula
$$
P_{2n+2} = (p+q)^2P_{2n}-\binom{2n}{n+1}p^{n+1}q^{n+1} +\binom{2n}{n}p^{n+2}q^n
$$
